# How can I detect an four corner from static image and crop it from the image using openCV?

Tags: java, android, opencv

When I take a picture with plain background my code work fine, but when I capture image from camera which has background then my code is not working.

**Here I have shared my code below:**

```
private void findPoints() {


    Mat image = new Mat();
    Mat orig = new Mat();
    org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(getResizedBitmap(mBitmap, MAX_HEIGHT), image);
    org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(mBitmap, orig);
    Mat edges = edgeDetection(orig);
    Imgproc.dilate(edges, edges, new Mat(), new Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, new Scalar(1));
    convertMatToBitmap(edges);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MatOfPoint> drawContours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    Mat linePic = Mat.zeros(edges.rows(), edges.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    List<MatOfPoint> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    List<MatOfPoint> hulls = new ArrayList<>();
    MatOfInt hull = new MatOfInt();
    MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f();
    approx.convertTo(approx, CvType.CV_32F);
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        MatOfPoint contour = contours.get(i);
   
        Imgproc.convexHull(contour, hull);
   
        Point[] contourPoints = contour.toArray();
        int[] indices = hull.toArray();
        List<Point> newPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index : indices) {
            newPoints.add(contourPoints[index]);
        }
        MatOfPoint2f contourHull = new MatOfPoint2f();
        contourHull.fromList(newPoints);
        
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contourHull, approx, Imgproc.arcLength(contourHull, true)*0.02, true);
        MatOfPoint mat = new MatOfPoint();
        mat.fromArray(approx.toArray());
        drawContours.add(mat);
    
        MatOfPoint approxf1 = new MatOfPoint();
        approx.convertTo(approxf1, CvType.CV_32S);
        if (approx.rows() == 4 && Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(approx)) > 40000 &&
                Imgproc.isContourConvex(approxf1)) {
            double maxCosine = 0;
            for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
                double cosine = Math.abs(getAngle(approxf1.toArray()[j%4], approxf1.toArray()[j-2], approxf1.toArray()[j-1]));
                maxCosine = Math.max(maxCosine, cosine);
            }
        
            if (maxCosine < 0.3) {
                MatOfPoint tmp = new MatOfPoint();
                contourHull.convertTo(tmp, CvType.CV_32S);
                squares.add(approxf1);
                hulls.add(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    //Here is to describe the extracted contour through different color lines, the specific effect can be seen by yourself
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < drawContours.size(); i++) {
        Imgproc.drawContours(linePic, drawContours, i, new Scalar(r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255)));
    }
    convertMatToBitmap(linePic);
    //7.Find the largest rectangle
    int index = findLargestSquare(squares);
    Log.d("index==",String.valueOf(index));
    MatOfPoint largest_square = squares.get(index);
    Mat polyPic = Mat.zeros(orig.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Imgproc.drawContours(polyPic, squares, index, new Scalar(0, 0,255), 2);
    convertMatToBitmap(polyPic);
  
    hull = new MatOfInt();
    Imgproc.convexHull(largest_square, hull, false);
    List<Integer> hullList =  hull.toList();
    List<Point> polyContoursList = largest_square.toList();
    List<Point> hullPointList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Point> lastHullPointList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < hullList.size();i++){
        Imgproc.circle(polyPic, polyContoursList.get(hullList.get(i)), 10, new Scalar(r.nextInt(255),r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), 3));
        hullPointList.add(polyContoursList.get(hullList.get(i)));
        System.out.println(hullList.get(i));
    }
    if(polyPic.size()==orig.size()){
        Log.d("size==","same size"+polyPic.size()+orig.size());
    }
    else {
        Log.d("size==","not same size"+polyPic.size()+orig.size());
    }
    //Core.addWeighted(polyPic, 0.5, orig, 0.5, 0, orig);
   // convertMatToBitmap(orig);
    for(int i = 0; i < hullPointList.size(); i++){
        lastHullPointList.add(hullPointList.get(i));
    }
    
    Point[] dstPoints = {new Point(0,0), new Point(orig.cols(),0), new Point(orig.cols(),orig.rows()), new Point(0,orig.rows())};
    Point[] srcPoints = new Point[4];
    boolean sorted = false;
    int n = 4;
   
    while (!sorted){
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            sorted = true;
            if (lastHullPointList.get(i-1).x > lastHullPointList.get(i).x){
                Point tempp1 = lastHullPointList.get(i);
                Point tempp2 = lastHullPointList.get(i-1);
                lastHullPointList.set(i, tempp2);
                lastHullPointList.set(i-1, tempp1);
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        n--;
    }


    if (lastHullPointList.get(0).y < lastHullPointList.get(1).y){
        srcPoints[0] = lastHullPointList.get(0);
        srcPoints[3] = lastHullPointList.get(1);
    }else{
        srcPoints[0] = lastHullPointList.get(1);
        srcPoints[3] = lastHullPointList.get(0);
    }
    if (lastHullPointList.get(2).y < lastHullPointList.get(3).y){
        srcPoints[1] = lastHullPointList.get(2);
        srcPoints[2] = lastHullPointList.get(3);
    }else{
        srcPoints[1] = lastHullPointList.get(3);
        srcPoints[2] = lastHullPointList.get(2);
    }
    List<Point> listSrcs = java.util.Arrays.asList(srcPoints[0], srcPoints[1], srcPoints[2], srcPoints[3]);
    Mat srcPointsMat = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(listSrcs, CvType.CV_32F);

    List<Point> dstSrcs = java.util.Arrays.asList(dstPoints[0], dstPoints[1], dstPoints[2], dstPoints[3]);
    Mat dstPointsMat = Converters.vector_Point_to_Mat(dstSrcs, CvType.CV_32F);
   
    Mat transMat = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(srcPointsMat, dstPointsMat);  
    Mat outPic = new Mat();
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(orig, outPic, transMat, orig.size());
    convertMatToBitmap(outPic);

   
}


private static double getAngle(Point pt1, Point pt2, Point pt0)
{
    double dx1 = pt1.x - pt0.x;
    double dy1 = pt1.y - pt0.y;
    double dx2 = pt2.x - pt0.x;
    double dy2 = pt2.y - pt0.y;
    return (dx1*dx2 + dy1*dy2)/Math.sqrt((dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1)*(dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2) + 1e-10);
}


private static int findLargestSquare(List<MatOfPoint> squares) {
    if (squares.size() == 0)
        return -1;
    int max_width = 0;
    int max_height = 0;
    int max_square_idx = 0;
    int currentIndex = 0;
    for (MatOfPoint square : squares) {
        Rect rectangle = Imgproc.boundingRect(square);
        if (rectangle.width >= max_width && rectangle.height >= max_height) {
            max_width = rectangle.width;
            max_height = rectangle.height;
            max_square_idx = currentIndex;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
    return max_square_idx;
}

/**
 * Detect the edges in the given Mat
 * @param src A valid Mat object
 * @return A Mat processed to find edges
 */
private Mat edgeDetection(Mat src) {
    Mat edges = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(edges, edges, new Size(5, 5), 0);
    Imgproc.Canny(edges, edges, 75, 200);
    return edges;
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this.?I got stuck on this for the past 1 week.

The output must me similar to the below link :
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/

Comment: Please provide some example of a working and not working image to make it clear what you are expecting to get.

Comment: I m getting exact output as u can find in above attach link , but with that image only. when i take image from camera then error is coming as index is -1.